# Where is config file set when using configurationmanager

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I am reading some other people's project "test" which does not have any other config file except "test.exe.config":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="testName" value="testCorrect">
</appSettings>
```

In the main:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Config: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testName"]);
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, it gives me the correct output.

I do not understand how this happens. I did not specify any configuration file and how the configuration manager knows which file it is.

Thanks

Derek

Comment: By convention it looks in `[executable name].config`

Comment: [What David said](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374182(v=vs.85).aspx), see the "File Name Syntax" section

Comment: But in my debug folder, I can only find "test.vshost.exe.config"

Comment: I see. I need set "Copy to Output Directory" true! Works perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @derek when you are running via VS and you have "use hosting process" option enabled the file will have name "app_name.vshots.exe.config" - it will not matter in runtime or if you disable the hosting process in options

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @David

To summarize,

ConfigurationManager will look for the following files:

- app.config
- web.config
- [exefilename.exe.config]

Enjoy.